# Why does mux.Vars() returns empty map[]

Tags: go, http, gorilla

I get an empty map[] from mux.Vars[].

After tracing the problem, it seems to be an empty `map[]` passed through my multiple files.

While in the same file: I have imported the other file as a module(I believe) in the `import`

```
package main

import(
"github.com/Ny0ttt/go-bookstore/pkg/controllers"
//note that this is imported from powershell, go mod init "github.com/Ny0ttt/go-bookstore"
)
```

while after running `go run main.go`, I obtain the map[] as **map[ID]**

While in a different file:

as per imported like the previous one, I receive an empty **map[]**

Here is my file structure

> Go-Test/cmd/main/main.exe
> Go-Test/cmd/main/main.go
> Go-Test/pkg/config/app.go
> Go-Test/pkg/models/models.go
> Go-Test/pkg/controllers/book-controller.go
> Go-Test/pkg/utils/utils.go
> Go-Test/go.sum
> Go-Test/go.mod

and my mod file contains

```
module github.com/Ny0ttt/go-bookstore

go 1.20

require (
    github.com/go-sql-driver/mysql v1.5.0
    github.com/gorilla/mux v1.8.0
    github.com/jinzhu/gorm v1.9.16
)

require github.com/jinzhu/inflection v1.0.0 // indirect
```

---

---

Here are my codes :

In my Controller

```
func GetBookById(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request){
    vars := mux.Vars(r)
    bookId := vars["ID"]
    ID, err := strconv.ParseInt(bookId, 0, 0)
    if err != nil{
        fmt.Println("error while parsing")
        fmt.Println(r)
        fmt.Println(bookId)
        fmt.Println(vars)
    }
    bookDetails, _ := models.GetBookById(ID) //mthis model returns 2 variable but we will be using only one of them. refer models
    res, _ := json.Marshal(bookDetails)
    w.Header().Set("Content-Type","pkglication/json")
    w.WriteHeader(http.StatusOK)
    w.Write(res)
}
```

In my Routes

```
func main() {
    r := mux.NewRouter()
    
    //routes.RegisterBookStoreRoutes(r)
    r.HandleFunc("/book/", controllers.GetBook).Methods("GET")
    r.HandleFunc("/book/", controllers.CreateBook).Methods("POST")
    r.HandleFunc("/book/{ID}", controllers.GetBookById).Methods("GET")
    r.HandleFunc("/book/{bookId}", controllers.UpdateBook).Methods("PUT")
    r.HandleFunc("/book/{bookId}", controllers.DeleteBook).Methods("DELETE")
        http.Handle("/", r)
    log.Fatal(http.ListenAndServe(":2222", r)) // creating a server
}
```

The output

```
error while parsing
&{GET /book/1 HTTP/1.1 1 1 map[Accept:[*/*] Accept-Encoding:[gzip, deflate, br] Connection:[keep-alive] Postman-Token:[a28eebe1-b6d4-4aff-89ed-d3b93a4ed1df] User-Agent:[PostmanRuntime/7.32.3]] {} <nil> 0 [] false :2222 map[] map[] <nil> map[] 127.0.0.1:52035 /book/1 <nil> <nil> <nil> 0xc000282a20}

map[]
```

Note: I print out the values so I can trace where it did go wrong, `*http.Request` does not map any values? I am not sure what map[] in return http.Request should look like.

I looked up for solutions, but it seems like i need more explaination on those alternatives. I have look up on `r.URL.Query` but the problem that they are facing is when using a different route structure.

I have also looked up for another alternative with `mux.RouteMatch` but I think I could use a little bit of explanation.

Comment: I can not reproduce the issue with this simple demo: https://go.dev/play/p/frd9XYtny8g. I sent the request with `curl 'http://localhost:2222/book/1'`. Please provide a minimal reproducer like this to show the issue.

Comment: @ZekeLu I have tested the code you provided, yes it works on my side too. I am currently looking back at my code. Sorry to not mention that I use modules using the `go mod init <link>` in my project. I am still looking into it.

Comment: @JonathanHall I have made the edits. Thank you for the advice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem Solved

I simply moved my project into the desktop (I am sure you may move wherever you want as long as you don't need administrator power to access the directory ) and it works.

I will continue exploring projects in a accessible directory from now on. Thank you.

Comment: `I simply moved my project into the desktop`. I don't think this change has anything to do with the original issue. I guess that you encountered the issue just because you forgot to recompile the source code after modifying.

Comment: I believe i compiled everytime before I run `go run main.go`. My previous directory is **C/Program Files/Go/src/go-bookstore** which will ask for permission whenever I try to add a folder in it without Administrator (I usually run powershell as administrator before i start to make directory for my coding project)

Comment: ohhh, you should not place your own code in the `C:\Program Files\Go\src` directory.

Comment: That explains everything. Thank you very much for your assistance. I really appreciate it! Thank you